# Fluid/Dynamic layout in Firemonkey / Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

Let's say I want two shapes on a form sitting side by side taking up exactly 50% of the window each, which resize when the window is resized. How can I do that?

What I really want is to set things up in ratios.. eg.. Have one of the above shapes take up 25% and the other take 75%

The dynamic resizing is very important, and I don't want to have to type any code to achieve this.

Comment: Seeing this voted down really ticks me off. How is this not a valid question? How can I improve my question without feedback.

Comment: I think it was voted down because of the negative phrasing ("very limited" versus "very different"). FireMonkey has scaleable layout possibilities like WPF, but it works in a different way. Make your question more neutral, and you will get more upvotes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Can be achieved by dropping a TLayout on the form - Setting the Align option to 'alscale'

Then adding 2 items to the TLayout I.e for my example TPanels - with align options on both set also to 'alscale'.  Set the widths of each to the ratio you want.

Form On Creation:

[image: Form on creation]

Form On Resize:
[image]

Can be achieved with 'no code -'for the images above I just added labels to display panel widths on form resize.
Hope this helps
Paul

Comment: Logged into my work machine remotely just to try it, success! Brilliant thanks

Comment: @NoPyGod Glad to help - have been helped here so much myself - Paul

Comment: So the problem is that the OP couldn't find the docs or the docs weren't very helpful.  Using one property (align) instead of two (VCL has align and anchors) is a design improvement in Firemonkey, IMHO, but if you have little history in Delphi, you might not have thought to try align without some more documentation.