# How to resize child controls when parent control is resized in delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, autoresize

I have a delphi form with specific `ClientHeight` and `ClientWidth` and 2 panels on it with certain width and height. When I resize the form, I want the panels to be resized automatically on runtime. How can I do this? Is there any built-in feature present in delphi to resize the child controls when parent controls are resized or I have to program it?

Comment: Check this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875691/fluid-dynamic-layout-in-firemonkey-delphi

Comment: I cannot find TLayout in Delphi XE2. How should I use this?

Comment: TLayout is only available in FireMonke. In VCL, maybe look at TFlowPanel instead.

Comment: Okay, will try this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the panel's [`Align`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Align) and/or [`Anchors`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.Anchors) properties.  They are designed for exactly this purpose.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to use Align and Anchor in this case?

Comment: I added links to the documentation.

Comment: Oh Sorry, I did not see the links and read as simple text. Yes Anchors property is doing my work. Thank you very much. I am accepting your answer.

Comment: Also, please answer my this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559156/unexpected-behaviour-of-ttable-and-tdbgrid-in-delphi-xe2

Comment: Sorry, I don't have much experience with TDBGrid. My DB experience is mostly non-visual work.

Comment: Its okay. But I needed it to be solved urgently. Nobody has answered or commented it yet. Can you refer somebody for this?