# How to use MessageDlg in OnClose Event of Delphi Form?

Tags: delphi, dialog, delphi-xe2

When my form is closed by clicking on 'Cross Button' or Alt + F4, I want user to ask whether he wants to close the application or not. If yes, I will terminate the application otherwise nothing to do. I am using following code on the onclose event of the form

```
procedure MyForm.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
var
  buttonSelected : integer;
begin
  buttonSelected := MessageDlg('Do you really want to close the application?',mtCustom, [mbYes,mbNo], 0);
  if buttonSelected = mrYES then
  begin
    Application.Terminate;
  end
  else
  begin
    //What should I write here to resume the application
  end;

end;
```

Whether I click Yes or No, my application is terminating. What should I do so that on No click of confirmation box, my application should not terminate. How should I improve my above function? Am I using right form event to implement this functionality? Please help..

Comment: You would have to use `Action` parameter, but it's better task for the `OnCloseQuery` event.

Comment: If that's your main form, then you don't need to call `Application.Terminate`. The application will go down once the main form is closed.

Comment: I hate when an application asks if I was really quite sure of I wanted it be gone.

Comment: @sertacAkyuz - But its the requirement

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - okay, removed application.terminate

Comment: Please also answer my this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13559156/unexpected-behaviour-of-ttable-and-tdbgrid-in-delphi-xe2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
var
  buttonSelected: integer;
begin
  buttonSelected := MessageDlg('Do you really want to close the application?', mtCustom, [mbYes, mbNo], 0);
  if buttonSelected = mrYES then
  begin
    CanClose:=true;
  end
  else
  begin
    CanClose:=false;
  end;
end;
```

or as @TLama advised, to simplify:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose := MessageDlg('Do you really want to close the application?', mtCustom, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrYES;
end;
```

Comment: You can also simplify this to one line `CanClose := MessageDlg('Do you really want to close the application?', mtCustom, [mbYes, mbNo], 0) = mrYES;`.

Answer (score 9):

The Window will stay open if you type

`Action := caNone;`

in your else Part