# How do I autosize a Firemonkey form

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, firemonkey-fm2

A VCL form has an AutoSize property to automatically adjust the form's size to its contents. I don't see a similar mechanism for Firemonkey. Short from manually calculating the size and setting Height and Width, is there a way?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11875691/fluid-dynamic-layout-in-firemonkey-delphi

Comment: That question is about dynamically sizing the components on the form. I want to dynamically size the form.

Comment: Yes, You should calculate Width = Max(ControlRects.Right) and Height = Max(ControlRects.Bottom).

Comment: Of course I can calculate the width and height. The question was if there is a way to do it automatically, as in VCL forms. Since the VCL form has this built in, I don't need to have code to update the form's size whenever a control inside it is changed.